# Create graph in LaTeX writer

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

How I can to create this graph in LaTeX writer? Please send me code of this graph for LaTeX.

Thank you.

Comment: `pgfplots` should do.

Comment: As the comments suggest, `pgfplots` is certainly able to handle this type of plot, as indeed are other plotting packages. Please show us the code you have tried and where your specific issues are. Asking for an arbitrary plot without any code is likely to result in the question being closed. We are very willing to help people, but this is a two-way street.

Comment: @All Please don't downvote further: the issues here seem clear enough.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what you mean by 'LaTeX writer': perhaps https://www.writelatex.com/

Comment: As the question has been closed, you'll need to edit and ask for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/example_96.tex) PGFPlots example seems close enough to your plot ([here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/example_96.pdf) is its PDF output). You can tweak it according to your needs; read the [PGFPlots documentation](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) to learn how.

Comment: I can not open this .tex file. Please send me only code

Comment: What do you mean? Can’t you open it in your editor (which editor do you use?)? Can’t you compile it (you can use `pdflatex example_96.tex`)?

Comment: And please, do bother to read about the etiquette of this site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour http://tex.stackexchange.com/help